# Wallabyjs with Bower and Requirejs (Visual Studio)

Tags: wallaby.js

I started using bower within my web application now and as I am using wallabyjs for testing I added

```
{ pattern: 'bower_components/**/*.*', instrument: false, load: false }
```

to my wallabyjs configuration. Everything is working fine that way. But as I've read in the [webpack documentation](http://wallabyjs.com/docs/integration/webpack.html) this is not really the recommended way:

> The more efficient approach that we would recommend is to specify an
>   absolute path in your wallaby configuration for webpack for your
>   external modules (not your source files) instead

I've tried to achieve something similar for my scenario (with requirejs) but failed. My current questions:

- What is the best way to handle the bower_components folder using requirejs/ wallabyjs?
- It seems that it is mandatory that the folder bower_components is a solution folder. As soon as I say "Exclude from project" within Visual Studio my tests fail again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case of require.js, you just need to let wallaby.js know where its internal web server should serve the files from. This way you may remove them from your `files` list and don't have to include to the solution.

You may do this by adding a [middleware function](http://wallabyjs.com/docs/config/middleware.html), that can map the web server paths to local folders:

```
 module.exports = function () {
   return {
     files: [
       ...
     ],

     tests: [
       ...
     ],

     // telling wallaby to serve bower_components project folder
     // ‘as is’ from the wallaby.js web server
     middleware: (app, express) => {
       app.use('/bower_components',
               express.static(
                  require('path').join(__dirname, 'bower_components')));
     }
   };
 };
```

*You may need to change the mapping depending on how your app requests bower_components.*

Comment: No, functions can only be defined in JS. Moving the JSON config file to JS is pretty straightforward though: just create a JS file with the same name, add `module.exports = function () { return ...;}` to it and paste your current JSON instead of the `...`.